# Scala: map with two or more Options

Tags: scala, scala-option

Basically I'm looking for the most scala-like way to do the following:

```
def sum(value1: Option[Int], value2: Option[Int]): Option[Int] = 
  if(value1.isDefined && value2.isDefined) Some(value1.get + value2.get)
  else if(value1.isDefined && value2.isEmpty) value1
  else if(value1.isEmpty && value2.isDefined) value2
  else None
```

This gives correct output:

```
sum(Some(5), Some(3))  // result = Some(8)
sum(Some(5), None)     // result = Some(5)
sum(None, Some(3))     // result = Some(3)
sum(None, None)        // result = None
```

Yet to sum more than two options I'd have to use way too many `if`s or use some sort of loop.

**EDIT-1:**

While writing the question I came up with sort of an answer:

```
def sum2(value1: Option[Int], value2: Option[Int]): Option[Int] = 
  value1.toList ::: value2.toList reduceLeftOption { _ + _ }
```

This one looks very idiomatic to my inexperienced eye. This would even work with more than two values. Yet is possible to do the same without converting to lists?

**EDIT-2:**

I ended up with this solution (thanks to **ziggystar**):

```
def sum(values: Option[Int]*): Option[Int] = 
  values.flatten reduceLeftOption { _ + _ }
```

**EDIT-3:**

Another alternative thanks to **Landei**:

```
def sum(values: Option[Int]*): Option[Int] = 
  values collect { case Some(n) => n } reduceLeftOption { _ + _ }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about:

```
scala> def sum(values: Option[Int]*): Option[Int] = values.flatten match {
     | case Nil => None                                                   
     | case l => Some(l.sum)                                              
     | }
sum: (values: Option[Int]*)Option[Int]

scala> sum(Some(1), None)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> sum(Some(1), Some(4))
res1: Option[Int] = Some(5)

scala> sum(Some(1), Some(4), Some(-5))
res3: Option[Int] = Some(0)

scala> sum(None, None)                
res4: Option[Int] = None
```

### Edit

Maybe it would be sane to return 0 if all arguments were None. In that case the function would reduce to `values.flatten.sum`.

Comment: Thanks for `flatten` I think that's what I was missing.

Answer (score 7):

```
scala> def sum(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int]) = (a,b) match {
     |   case (Some(x), Some(y)) => Some(x + y)
     |   case (Some(x), None) => Some(x)
     |   case (None, Some(y)) => Some(y)
     |   case _ => None
     | }
sum: (a: Option[Int],b: Option[Int])Option[Int]

scala> sum(Some(5), Some(3))
res0: Option[Int] = Some(8)

scala> sum(Some(5), None)
res1: Option[Int] = Some(5)

scala> sum(None, Some(3))
res2: Option[Int] = Some(3)

scala> sum(None, None)
res3: Option[Int] = None
```

Comment: Thanks. It is more idiomatic in a sense that is uses `match` instead of `if`. Otherwise it's the same code as my first example, with the same limitations - you'd have to add much more `case`s to sum more than 2 values.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is:

```
def sum(values: Option[Int]*): Int = values.collect{case Some(n) => n}.sum
```

While in the current case `flatten` is clearly more convenient, the `collect` version is more flexible, as it allows to perform mappings and to have additional filter conditions or complex patterns. E.g. imagine you want to have the sum of the squares of all even numbers in values:

```
values.collect{case Some(n) if n mod 2 == 0 => n*n}.sum
```

Comment: The compiler complains about returned type: found `Int`, required `Option[Int]`. I see your point about `collect` method instead of `flatten`, but I still have to do `reduceLeftOption` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

You can make it very concise using the fact that there is an `Semigroup` instance for `Option` that does exactly what you want.  You can use [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) or [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats).  Here is an example using `cats`:

```
import cats.std.option._
import cats.syntax.semigroup._
import cats.std.int._

Option(1) |+| Option(2) // Some(3)
Option(1) |+| None      // Some(1)
None      |+| Option(2) // Some(2)
```

So your `sum` becomes:

```
def sum(v1: Option[Int], v2: Option[Int]): Option[Int] = v1 |+| v2
```

Answer (score 4):

Reduced solution of michael.kebe with a little look to some basic mathematical rules:

```
def sum(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int]) = (a,b) match {
  case (None,None) => None
  case _ => Some(a.getOrElse(0)+b.getOrElse(0))
}

scala> sum(Some(5), Some(3))  // result = Some(8)
res6: Option[Int] = Some(8)

scala> sum(Some(5), None)     // result = Some(5)
res7: Option[Int] = Some(5)

scala> sum(None, Some(3))     // result = Some(3)
res8: Option[Int] = Some(3)

scala> sum(None, None)        // result = None
res9: Option[Int] = None
```